# Generating a random number between several intervals in php

Tags: php, laravel, random, intervals

I'd like to create a random number between several intervals in php. So I have several intervals in my database and I would like to randomly generate a number belonging to one of these intervals.
I have already thought of selecting a random interval and then generating a random number within that interval but I think there are much simpler and optimized methods. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don’t see at which point you expect something “simpler” here. Of course you will have to select an interval first, before you can get random numbers inside of that interval.

Comment: Please post an example and your less "simpler" approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random_int()`

```
function random_int($min, $max) { }

@param int $min
The lowest value to be returned, which must be PHP_INT_MIN or higher.

@param int $max
The highest value to be returned, which must be less than or equal to PHP_INT_MAX.

@return int
Returns a cryptographically secure random integer in the range min to max, inclusive.
random_int($min, $max)
```

Assuming you already have `$intervals` list, you can loop through it.

```
foreach($intervals as $interval) {
    random_int($interval['min'], $interval['max']);
}
```

Comment: I think the idea is *generate a number belonging to one of these intervals* and not each one.

Answer (score 1):

$numbers = range(1, 20);

shuffle($numbers);